# addClass multiple classes not working on select

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a an alternative array that takes in `shift_types` in my model as followed:

```
  SHIFT_TYPES = %w(Half Full Semi-Foo)
```

and in my view I have below

```
<%= f.select(:shift_type, HospitalBooking::SHIFT_TYPES.each_with_index { |e,i| [i,e] }) %>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that depending on which shift type is selected the background of the table cell changes. So what I have done is tried to use the .addclass by doing the following in my application.js

```
$('.rota td').addClass("Half Full Semi-Foo");
```

and in the css it is set as

```
.Half{ background-color: green;
}

.Full{ background-color: #ff0000;}

.Semi-Foo { background-color: #ffff00;}
```

I am sure this set up is correct. However it appears that when I make a booking and select a shift type the table cell does not change.

Comment: So it could be a Rails problem or it could be a JavaScript problem. Show us what the rendered HTML looks like in addition to the view.

Comment: @Cymen - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5001567

Answer (score 0):

Have you try something like this:

```js
$("#hospital_booking_shift_type").change(function(){
  $(this).closest('td').removeClass('Half Full Semi-Foo').addClass($(this).val())
})
```

Comment: No I have not tried this, however I have noticed that I am now getting the following output with my current code above - http://i.imgur.com/qBpFoEe.png. I also have tried the above as you suggested this did not work